# Constant error in Tomcat logs for MySQL NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/cj/protocol/ExportControlled

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot API which has both a MySQL and a Mongo DB. Now when running locally everything works well...no errors in the logs.

Now the second I deploy this to Tomcat in my production environment (Debian 10) I constantly see the below in the logs.

Now just to say, that the Spring -> MySQL inserts and queries work fine no issues. Its just this error constantly filling up the logs...really stumped on this one!

Thanks for taking the time!

```
Exception in thread "HikariPool-5 connection closer" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/cj/protocol/ExportControlled
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.NetworkResources.forceClose(NetworkResources.java:53)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.AbstractSocketConnection.forceClose(AbstractSocketConnection.java:103)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.quit(NativeProtocol.java:1227)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.quit(NativeSession.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:1733)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:721)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.quietlyCloseConnection(PoolBase.java:143)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.lambda$closeConnection$1(HikariPool.java:451)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Exception in thread "HikariPool-5 connection closer" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/cj/protocol/ExportControlled
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.NetworkResources.forceClose(NetworkResources.java:53)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.AbstractSocketConnection.forceClose(AbstractSocketConnection.java:103)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.quit(NativeProtocol.java:1227)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.quit(NativeSession.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:1733)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:721)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.quietlyCloseConnection(PoolBase.java:143)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.lambda$closeConnection$1(HikariPool.java:451)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: Are you using a different database connector on your prod machine? 
The connector for Debian 10 [Connector/J 8.0.21](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) (`/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar`) contains the missing class.

Comment: Hi Freddy, should be the same as I'm just pulling it in via gradle?
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.21'

Comment: check if you have several version of the driver in your production environment (e.g. check if there is a jar in the lib directory of tomcat)

Comment: can you list java classpath available on system and filter out all jar that contains mysql text

Comment: Please post your dependency manager configuration (maven/gradle).

Comment: The problem is that you are ***mixing*** different versions of `mysql-connector`. Based on which version of spring boot you are using, default managed version differs. `ExportControlled` is found in version 8 of `mysql-connector`, so check the version found in your prod.